# 7Zip - Powershell - $LastExitCode Issues

Tags: powershell, 7zip

Pretty sure just me not knowing what to do but I am having issues with a 7zip PS script and the $LastExitCode

```
ForEach ($File in $Files) {
    
    7zip a “$DestDir\$file.7z” "$SourceDir\$File” -m0=LZMA2 -mx=9 -mmt4 | findstr /I "archive everything error" | Out-File $LOGPath -Force -Append
    7zip t "$DestDir\$file.7z" | findstr /I "testing size compressed archive everything error" | Out-File $LOGPath -Force -Append

    if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
        Write-Output  “Compression SUCCEEDED and zip file tested OK” | Out-File $LOGPath -Force -Append
        Write-Output  “DELETING ORIGINAL file - $File `n” | Out-File $LOGPath -Force -Append
        Remove-Item -Path “$SourceDir\$File” | Out-File $LOGPath -Force -Append
    }
    else {
        Write-Output “Compression FAILED, source file not deleted `n” | Out-File $LOGPath -Force -Append
    }
}
```

This is the script (important bits)

It does a zip then a test of the created package

So to test that the $LastExitCode is working (or not), I # out the zip part and leave the test step and remove any zip files from the destination folder. The zip test step fails as expected and sends an error to log (Error:cannot find archive) but still goes through with the remove-item, which should only occur if the test passes I would have throught??

Not sure what I am doing worng here? Or if this is the incorrect way to go about this?

I want to create the archive, confirm it is OK, then delete the original source file if it is (i.e. no errors).

Any advice really apprecited

thanks

EDIT

Ended up with below that seems to do the trick - thanks for the advice

```
ForEach ($File in $Files) {

Write-Output “Compressing $File” | Out-File $LOGPath -Force -Append
7zip a "$DestDir\$file.7z” "$SourceDir\$File" -m0=LZMA2 -mx=9 -mmt4
        
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
    Write-Output  "Compression SUCCEEDED" | Out-File $LOGPath -Force -Append
    Write-Output “TESTING compressed file - $File” | Out-File $LOGPath -Force -Append
    7zip t "$DestDir\$file.7z"                     

        if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
            Write-Output  "Zip file tested OK" | Out-File $LOGPath -Force -Append
            Write-Output  "DELETING original file - $File `n" | Out-File $LOGPath -Force -Append
            #Remove-Item -Path “$SourceDir\$File” | Out-File $LOGPath -Force -Append
        }
            else {
                Write-Output “Zip test FAILED, source file not deleted `n” | Out-File $LOGPath -Force -Append
            }
  }                            

    else {
        Write-Output "Compression FAILED for file - $file - moving onto next file" | Out-File $LOGPath -Force -Append
    }
```

}

Comment: Some of your quotation marks are strange. Please change them to normal quotation marks.

Comment: Note that your ```$LASTEXITCODE``` is testing the exit code from ```findstr```, not ```7zip``` - is that what you’re expecting?

Comment: @PalleDue - thanks - that may be from a copy/paste - I will correct

Comment: added updated code to the initial post - seems to do the trick - thanks for the advice (the quotes sem to copy/paste incorectly - they are correct in sorce)